# How many vehicles were involved in Operation Gothic Serpent (Mogadishu, October 3-4, 1993)?

Tags: united-states, military, 20th-century, africa, battle

I wanted to know how many vehicles (include their model and which country used it), aircraft and infantry were deployed in [Operation Gothic Serpent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Gothic_Serpent) in Mogadishu in October 1993.

Specific numbers of:

1. Aircraft and their models.
2. Vehicles and their models (Oct 3 — US Vehicles and Technical and
   another separate for Oct 4 vehicles and tanks).
3. Rangers involved (among 160 men, how many were rangers on Oct 3 then
   how many more were added for the rescue ops on Oct 4).
4. Delta operators involved (how many snipers also) .
5. How many Pakistani and Malaysian infantry were involved on the
   rescue.

As far as I know, there were 16 helos among 18 aircraft. 8 being the Blackhawks and 8 being the Little Bird attack helicopters.

Vehicles were composed (Oct 3) of at least 9 Humvees, 3 M939 5-Ton Trucks (Oct 4) M48 Tanks, and Condor Armored Vehicles.

Comment: Can you specify what about the [readily available numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Gothic_Serpent) you consider unsatisfactory? You seem to have a rather good idea of what materiel was involved; what exactly is left open to question?

Comment: To comment on the use of the OH-6 and OH-58 and the P-3 during the operation https://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/28177/these-secret-helicopters-were-flown-by-a-shadowy-unit-during-the-battle-of-mogadishu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the information that you are interested in is available directly from the Wikipedia page on [Operation Gothic Serpent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Gothic_Serpent). However, other details do seem to be rather more elusive.

US Forces deployed on 3 October included [US Army Delta Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Force), [Rangers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Army_Rangers), an air element from the [160th Special Operation Aviation Regiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/160th_Special_Operations_Aviation_Regiment_(Airborne)) (the "Night Stalkers"), four [Navy SEALs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Navy_SEALs) from SEAL team 6, and [US Air Force Para-rescue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Air_Force_Pararescue) Combat Controllers.

I've pulled together the information that I can find to answer your specific questions below:

---

### Aircraft and their models.

- The Air assault force was delivered by four MH-6 Little Bird helicopters & two MH-60 Black Hawk helicopters
- Ranger blocking force was delivered by four MH-60 Black Hawk helicopters
- Four AH-6 gunship helicopters for CAS
- One MH-60 Black Hawk helicopter with combat search & rescue (CSAR) - designated Super 68
- Air observation force comprising 3 surveillance helicopters (one OH-58 and two OH-6) and one Navy P3 Orion surveillance aircraft

Giving a total of 19 aircraft:

- 4x [MH-6 Little Bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD_Helicopters_MH-6_Little_Bird) helicopters

[image: MH-6 Little Bird] (Click to enlarge)

(image source [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=70769685))

- 4x AH-6 gunship helicopters (attack variant of the MH-6)
- 7x [MH-60 Black Hawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_UH-60_Black_Hawk) helicopters

[image: MH-60 Black Hawk] (Click to enlarge)

(image source [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=68331017))

- 1x [OH-58 helicopter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_OH-58_Kiowa)

[image: OH-58 Helicopter] (Click to enlarge)

(image source [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=48211066))

- 2x [OH-6 helicopters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hughes_OH-6_Cayuse)

[image: Hughes OH-6] (Click to enlarge)

(image source [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=9545729))

- 1x Navy [P3 Orion surveillance aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_P-3_Orion)

[image: P3 Orion] (Click to enlarge)

(image source [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=62312428))

---

### Vehicles and their models

**October 3**

- 3rd Platoon of B Company, under the command of Lieutenant Colonel McKnight, operated the ground convoy of 9x [High-Mobility Multipurpose Wheeled Vehicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humvee) (HMMWVs or 'Humvees') and 3x [M939 5-Ton Trucks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M939_series_5-ton_6x6_truck)
- Later in the day, Ground reaction force 2 (GRF2), consisting of 27 Rangers commanded by SSg Strucker led a relief force of 2x M939 5-Ton trucks and 6x 'Humvees'
- Also later in the day, Company C, from the 10th Mountain Division Quick Reaction Force (QRF) - 150 soldiers (including an engineer squad and a medical team with the battalion surgeon) in 12x 'Humvees' and nine [M35 2½-ton trucks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M35_series_2%C2%BD-ton_6x6_cargo_truck)

**October 4**

Sources are unclear about the exact breakdown of US vehicles dispatched with the relief convoy on 4 October. The total number varies between 70 and 100 vehicles depending on the sources consulted.

However, it is clear that a large American force of 'Humvees', M35 2½-ton trucks, and M939 5-Ton trucks was accompanied by 32x Malaysian [Condor Armoured Personnel Carriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condor_(APC)) and 4 Pakistani [M48 tanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M48_Patton).

---

### Rangers involved

Three platoons of Company B, 3rd Battalion, 75th Ranger Regiment were deployed on 3 October plus 7 Ranger para-rescue specialists deployed with CSAR.

Two platoons of Company B, 3rd Battalion, 75th Ranger Regiment, commanded by Captain Mike Steele loaded into four MH60Ls to form the blocking chalks.

- 1st Platoon of B Company, commanded by First Lieutenants Larry Perino
  (Chalk 1 & Chalk 3)
- 2nd Platoon of B Company, commanded by First Lieutenant Thomas Di
  Tomasso (Chalk 2 & Chalk 4)
- 3rd Platoon of B Company, under the command of Lieutenant Colonel
  McKnight, operated the ground convoy to exfiltrate the prisoners (and
  potentially all of the Rangers and Delta)

A further 27 Rangers would subsequently be deployed with Ground reaction force 2 (GRF2).

---

### Delta operators involved

- An initial 'impact force' of 16 men from the 1st Special Forces Operational Detachment-Delta (Delta force) (one four-man team carried by each MH-6)
- The initial force was supported by 30 men from the 1st Special Forces Operational Detachment-Delta (Delta force) carried by two MH-60 Black Hawk helicopters

The Delta force detachment included at least 8 snipers.

---

### How many Pakistani and Malaysian infantry were involved on the rescue.

More than 100 Malaysian soldiers of the [*19 Melayu Diraja Mekanise*](http://english.astroawani.com/malaysia-news/untold-story-black-hawk-down-23121) troop accompanied the relief convoy on 4 October.  Malaysian [Corporal Mat Aznan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat_Aznan_Awang) was killed and nine other Malaysian soldiers were injured.

At least 16 soldiers from the Pakistan UN detachment also accompanied the convoy. However, as far as I can ascertain, these were tank crews, and not infantry. One Pakistani soldier was killed and two were wounded.

---

### Sources

- Major Roger N. Sanviv, Militray Intelligence, [Battle of Mogadishu: Anatomy of a Failure](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a366316.pdf), School of Advanced Military Study, USAC & GSC, Fort Leavenworth, Kansas.
- Thomas Di Tomasso, [The Battle of the Black Sea: Bravo Company, 3rd Ranger Battalion, 75th Ranger Regiment 3-4 October 1993](http://www.benning.army.mil/library/content/Virtual/Donovanpapers/other/STUP5/DiTomassoThomas%20CPT.pdf), USAIS Library, Ft Benning, GA
- US Senate: [Review of the Circumstances Surrounding the Ranger Raid on October 3-4 1993 in Mogadishu, Somalia](https://fas.org/irp/congress/1995_rpt/mogadishu.pdf), 1995
- Denver Meyers: [Battle of Mogadishu](http://cgsc.contentdm.oclc.org/cdm/singleitem/collection/p15040coll2/id/2517/rec/2), USASMA Digital Library
- Bryan W. Olsen: [Battle of Mogadishu, 3 Oct 93](http://cgsc.contentdm.oclc.org/cdm/singleitem/collection/p15040coll2/id/600/rec/1), USASMA Digital Library
- Craig D. Owens: [Operation Gothic Serpent](http://cgsc.contentdm.oclc.org/utils/getdownloaditem/collection/p15040coll2/id/1492/filename/1493.pdf/mapsto/pdf/type/singleitem), USASMA Digital Library
- Mark Bowden: [Black Hawk Down](https://archive.org/stream/black-hawk-down_201701/black-hawk-down#page/n0), New American Library, 1999
- Fred J. Pushies: [Night Stalkers: 160th Special Operations Aviation Regiment (Airborne)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CyGuaWpdZ3AC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), Zenith, 2005
- Shaun Joseph Edge: [The growing role of Special Forces in modern warfare with specific reference to the United States of America](https://repository.up.ac.za/bitstream/handle/2263/27310/dissertation.pdf;sequence=1). Pretoria, 2010
- Clayton Chun, [Gothic Serpent: Black Hawk Down Mogadishu 1993](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Id-6CwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), Bloomsbury Publishing, 2012